# "Mail Authentication Request" prompt

Tags: password, thunderbird, email

My brother uses Thunderbird 31.6.0 on Linux Mint 17.1 (Cinnamon) and when he forwards me a message (I am on Lubuntu 14.04.1), it prompts me with a "Mail Authentication Request" for my email provider's password.

> Mail authentication request
>   Please enter the password for mail account "1and1.net"

How may that be stopped?
Will responding send my email password back to the sender?
Since I have already logged in, why do I need to relogin?
Using the correct password did not solve the issue.

Comment: Does your email password not work?

Comment: You may find this helpful. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_SMTP_Authentication Be aware that questions regarding Mint are off-topic here and your question is likely to be closed for that reason. For further information please see  the "Be on topic" section of http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask I would assume that it's "prompting him" and not you as there's no reason you would be prompted to authenticate for his SMTP server. Although you may be prompted for your SMTP server if you are sending mail.

Comment: Responding won't send your password to them, but that is weird. Check the authentication settings to see if there's some sort of "Remember Credentials" option.

Comment: @Elder Geek ' ' I would assume that it's "prompting him" and not you as there's no reason you would be prompted to authenticate for his SMTP server. ' '   Well, since I am receiving it from my ISP and my ISP is named in the message, I am baffled, especially since I am not trying to send it on to someone else, just to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP is asking you to login to your SMTP server so that you can respond to a return receipt request.